# How to disable Powerlevel10k in Warp and install Starship

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2, warp

I just installed Warp terminal and I'm loving it.

But I want to customize the prompt with Starship and still having Powerlevel10k on my iTerm2 terminal. Does it is posible?

Comment: I'm an going through exactly the same problem. Also at the point of reinstalling everything and remove p10k completely. Startship prompt customization is working fine on iTerm2 but not working on Warp.

Comment: I managed to make it work. Could you update you question with your .zshrc and starship.toml files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours I managed to install Starship on Warp and still having Powerlevel10k on iTerm (and all the others terminals ) modifying my `.zshrc` file as the [Warp documentation](https://docs.warp.dev/features/prompt#powerlevel10k-p10k) says.

So at the start of the file I wrapped the Powelevel10k initialization to only activate it if the terminal is not Warp:

```
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM != "WarpTerminal" ]]; then
    if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
      source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
    fi
fi
```

And I wrapped the Starship initialization only for Warp at the end of the file:

```
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM == "WarpTerminal" ]]; then
    eval "$(starship init zsh)"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add to @Christian answer small hint in case of still missing prompt:

```
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM == "iTerm.app" ]]; then
  test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"
fi
```

That shell integration quite often cause a issue (e.g. https://github.com/warpdotdev/Warp/issues/1518) - the same was for me and the conditional initialisation helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has tried the technique for fixing Powerlevel10k or Starship without success, check if you have Powershell installed.

### Powershell Issues

I was having this issue, and I thought it was because of Powerlevel, but it was because of Powerline!

[image: Warp keeps adding extra content like 'Username > Documents > DirectoryName > app']

[image: Terminal screenshot]

### The Fix

In my `~/.bash_profile` I had:

```
. /Users/dilraj/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
```

I updated it to:

```
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM != "WarpTerminal" ]]; then
  # Powerline - Do not run in Warp.dev
  . /Users/dilraj/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
```

Then run `source ~/.bash_profile` and exit and re-open your command line interfaces! Wrap is good for me now!